# AzureStorage: Server failed to authenticate the request. Make sure the value of Authorization header is formed correctly including the signature

Tags: .net, oauth, azure-storage, azure-blob-storage

I almost went through all the SO answers related to this and other forums but I am still not able to figure out the actual issue. This app is console app which will be deployed on On-Premise environment and will upload files to Azure blob.

I am using WindowsAzure.Storage 9.3.3 with code below.

```
static void CreateBlob(string accountName, string containerName, string blobName, string accessToken)
{
        var tokenCredential = new TokenCredential(accessToken);
        var storageCredentials = new StorageCredentials(tokenCredential);
        var storageAccount = new CloudStorageAccount(storageCredentials, accountName, string.Empty, useHttps: true);
        var cloudBlobClient = storageAccount.CreateCloudBlobClient();

        var cloudBlobContainer = cloudBlobClient.GetContainerReference(containerName);
        CloudBlockBlob blockBlob = cloudBlobContainer.GetBlockBlobReference(blobName);

        string blobContents = "Blob created by Azure AD authenticated user.";
        byte[] byteArray = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(blobContents);

        try
        {
            using (MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream(byteArray))
            {
                blockBlob.UploadFromStreamAsync(stream).Wait();
            }
            Console.WriteLine("upload successful");
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
}
```

And to get the token like below.

```
        public static string GetOAuthToken(string activeDirectoryTenantId, string  
           activeDirectoryApplicationSecret, string activeDirectoryApplicationId)
        {
            string resourceId = $"https://storage.azure.com";
            var authority = String.Format("https://login.windows.net/" + activeDirectoryTenantId);

            var credential = new ClientCredential(activeDirectoryApplicationId, activeDirectoryApplicationSecret);

            var context = new AuthenticationContext(authority);
            var result = context.AcquireTokenAsync(resourceId, credential).Result;

            return result.AccessToken;
        }
```

Could any one please suggest what I might be missing?
P/S I have already confirmed my local system is in sync with correct UTC time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I tried with the code in your issue, it uploaded blob successfully.

[image]

**Note:**

1. Assign `Storage Blob Data Contributor` role to the application

Navigate to Storage account -> Access Control (IAM) -> Add role assignment

[image]

2. Grant your registered app permissions to Azure Storage following this [step](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/common/storage-auth-aad-app?tabs=dotnet#grant-your-registered-app-permissions-to-azure-storage).

[image]

Comment: Yeah for me second step was missing. thanks